# Lodash performance hit with _.uniqWith to remove duplicate objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, big-o, lodash

I'm using `_.uniqWith` in Lodash to remove duplicate objects from an array of ~6,000 objects:

```
let uniqColors = _.uniqWith(colorCollection, _.isEqual);
```

Where a sample object in the array looks like:

```
{
  r: 122,
  g: 44,
  b: 216
}
```

It takes about 8500ms on average to process. Is there a way to speed up this type of function, using `_.uniqBy()` or another Lodash function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution in vanilla JavaScript that takes 4ms to process 6000 random entries in Chrome on my machine.

I convert the colors to their integer equivalents, and then use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to keep track of duplicates:

```js
const getRandomData = (n) => {
  const result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    result.push({
      r: Math.floor((Math.random() * 256)),
      g: Math.floor((Math.random() * 256)),
      b: Math.floor((Math.random() * 256))
    });
  }
  
  return result;
}

const hash = (color) => (color.r << 16) + (color.g << 8) + color.b;

const n = 6000;
const data = getRandomData(n);

const start = performance.now();

const set = new Set();
const result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  const color = data[i];
  const key = hash(color);
  
  if (!set.has(key)) {
    set.add(key);
    result.push(color);
  }
}

const end = performance.now();

console.log(`Removed ${n - result.length} duplicates from ${n} items`);
console.log(`Operation took ${end - start} ms`);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not aware of `Set()` which seems like a more robust / extensible solution. I found a way to do it in Lodash as well:

```
let uniqColors = _.uniqBy(colorCollection, function (e) { return e.r + ' ' + e.g + ' ' + e.b; });
```

Comment: Cool. See if you can speed it up by using integers instead of strings: `_.uniqBy(colorCollection, c => c.r * 65536 + c.g * 256 + c.b)`

Comment: Wow integers increase performance by ~30%. Where can I learn more about how this works?

Comment: In the end it all comes down to the bytes. An RGB color can be represented using 3 bytes, so the most efficient implementation will only have to compare 3 bytes vs 3 bytes each time. In my approach, I use numbers which already take up 8 bytes. Your conversion to string results in about 10 characters per number, so that's 20 bytes. The `Set` I use is a convenient data structure that sorts data into different buckets, making it faster to perform lookups. Pretty sure that the time of my solution can still easily be cut in half, if not more.

Comment: Btw, can probably even save more if the order of the result is not important.